# Why do my bathroom lights keep blowing?

Tags: light

Hello:  I have a wall mount light fixture that uses 5 globe type bulbs.  I have had the fixture for about 10 years, recently each time I replace a bulb - the new bulb burns out within a few hours.  Only the two end bulbs remain lighted.

Can someone let me know what might be causing the 3 bulbs to keep burning out so quickly?  I've been using both GE & Sylvania 40 watt incandescent bulbs.

Comment: Are any other appliances in your house acting odd? Is the toaster cooking slower than it used to?

Comment: Nope, there are no other electrical issues.